# Error with rails after update to 4.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rvm

recently I have updated to rails 4.0.0.rc1 and I have been experiencing a few errors. I am currently using RVM as well. After creating a rails 4 app and running 'rails s' or 'rspec rails' i got the error -

```
/Users/metaHunts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into Hash (TypeError)
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `new'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `generator='
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:17:in `<module:Ext>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:58:in `<module:JSON>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:11:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails.rb:9:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/Desktop/TeenStarter/config/application.rb:4:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/Desktop/TeenStarter/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `require'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Users/metaHunts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have tried reloading rvm, cleaing and repairing it as well yet I keep getting the same error. Could I please have some help in fixing it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing RVM with

```
rvm implode
```

before reinstalling it with the command on rvm website (https://rvm.io/).

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. For some reason I don't know it got fixed by running:

```
gem install json -v 1.7.7
```